# link against a legacy library: -lgfortranbegin from a premade makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, gfortran, legacy-code

I got some trouble trying to compile a programm developed by some researcher supposed to compute in a very precise way fourier transform and some other useful operation [scientific paper here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Gerard_Gomez2/publication/267653088_A_collocation_method_for_the_numerical_Fourier_analysis_of_quasi-periodic_functions_II_Analytical_error_estimates/links/54c750970cf289f0ceccf26a.pdf), whereas all the files needed and the makefile are provided.

I use gcc and a version of ubuntu available on windows10 (18.04), so, I linked all the librabries needed by the program and called in the pre-made makefile (fftw, lapack, gfortran..) everything is ok untill here, but once I tried to compile I got the error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortranbegin
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:38: recipe for target 'furian_main' failed
make: *** [furian_main] Error 1
```

After a few research it appears that libfortranbegin is a legacy code and no more available(source: [here](https://root-forum.cern.ch/t/cant-find-libgfortranbegin-a-when-installing-root-6-06-04/21222) ) ..

So my question is: is it possible for me to compile my program without this legacy library (somme people say that we could get rid off this library, but I didn't understand what they do .. [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40267))
Or should I do some update or use another library ?

Thank you for your time and consideration :)

Comment: Looks like you need GNU FORTRAN GCC package, this library should be bundled.

Comment: I already have it, I installed it via the command "Sudo apt install gfortan"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way of solving this is the following one:

- remove the `-lgfortranbegin`
- check the new link errors and look at what source file from the original source code implemented this feature
- add this source file to your repository and your build and go back to step 2.

Be aware that it may still not work in the end, but hopefully you will be able to have the missing symbols.

Comment: what do you mean by "add this file to your repository" ? the new error messages I get are something like:
    `undefined reference to 'dscal_' [...]`

and most of my source files are already in my repository

Comment: You have to add the file with the source code to your build (sorry, it wasn't clear enough).

Comment: Yes, just remove the `-lgfortranbegin`, it is an obsolete thing.

Comment: OK, so the missing `dscal` is a Fortran function (hence the suffix `_`). Find it in the gfortranbegin source code and compile the source file in your project.

Comment: There is no dscal in gfortranbegin! What would it do there? It is in BLAS. Libgfortranbegin is **completely obsolete**, just remove the link command, it is useless.

Comment: Oh indeed. So you need to add `-lblas` instead of `-lgfortranbegin`

Comment: ok, so that should be my link with the blas library that I did wrong.. I will defenitly remove the -lgfortranbegin and focus on the liking of the other libraries